# Access 2007 list all the Sunday and Saturday in a year?

Tags: vba, microsoft-access-2007

Is there any way to list all the Sunday and Saturday for a given year (2013 for example) in Access ? I tried to search and see that VBA might do the trick.
What I want is that I have a Form that ask for user to input [Start Date] and [End Date]. I want to calculate the [Working days] = [End Date] - [Start Date] - (any Sunday and Saturday in between if available). So I am thinking of listing all the Sunday and Saturday in that year first then somehow trying to calculate the [Working days].
Any ideas would be appreciate . Thank you. >.<

Ok I managed to come up with simple function that can track down the Saturday in a period of time. haha guess I can solve it myself

```
Private Sub Command38_Click()
    str = FindWeekend(#6/3/2013#, #6/17/2013#)
    MsgBox str
End Sub


Public Function FindWeekend(ByVal StartDate As Date, ByVal EndDate As Date) As String
    Dim Weekend() As Date
    Dim i, k As Integer

    i = 0

    Do Until StartDate = EndDate
        If Weekday(StartDate) = 7 Then
            ReDim Preserve Weekend(i)
            Weekend(i) = StartDate
            i = i + 1
        End If
        StartDate = StartDate + 1
        MsgBox StartDate
    Loop

    'Convert stored value to string to debug
    For k = 0 To UBound(Weekend)
        FindWeekend = FindWeekend & Format(Weekend(k), "dd-mm-yyyy") & ","
    Next k

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

If you search for **work days** in Access developer reference, it gives you code that will do that calculation for you

[Reproduced for posterity]

```
Function Work_Days(BegDate As Variant, EndDate As Variant) As Integer
   Dim WholeWeeks As Variant
   Dim DateCnt As Variant
   Dim EndDays As Integer

   On Error GoTo Err_Work_Days

   BegDate = DateValue(BegDate)
   EndDate = DateValue(EndDate)
   WholeWeeks = DateDiff("w", BegDate, EndDate)
   DateCnt = DateAdd("ww", WholeWeeks, BegDate)
   EndDays = 0

   Do While DateCnt <= EndDate
      If Format(DateCnt, "ddd") <> "Sun" And Format(DateCnt, "ddd") <> "Sat" Then
         EndDays = EndDays + 1
      End If
      DateCnt = DateAdd("d", 1, DateCnt)
   Loop

   Work_Days = WholeWeeks * 5 + EndDays

Exit Function

    Err_Work_Days:

    ' If either BegDate or EndDate is Null, return a zero
    ' to indicate that no workdays passed between the two dates.

    If Err.Number = 94 Then
        Work_Days = 0
        Exit Function
    Else
' If some other error occurs, provide a message.
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
    End If

End Function
```